# confirm message not working

Tags: javascript, php

The confirm message in my href link is not working.

here is My code:

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="'.$delete_url.'" title="delete"  onclick="return  confirm("Are you sure you want to Remove?");">
  <img   src="'.base_url().'images/dashboard-delete-icon.png" alt="delete icon" role="presentation" width="14" height="16"/>
</a>'?>
```

Please help, what mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Use quotes properly `onclick="return  confirm('Are you sure you want to Remove?');"`, As I am not well of in php take care of syntax

Comment: @jeroen, I know, as I am not good in PHP tried to guide OP in correct direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onclick` handler ends after the double quote before `"Are`.

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.$delete_url.'" title="delete"  onclick="return  confirm("Are you sure you want to Remove?");">
```

You should use a single quote and escape it so that you can echo it properly from php:

```
... onclick="return  confirm(\'Are you sure you want to Remove?\');"> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your quotes :

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.$delete_url.'" title="delete"  onclick="return  confirm("Are you sure you want to Remove?");">
```

**Replace your `onclick` with :**

```
onclick="return  confirm(\'Are you sure you want to Remove?\');">
```